# systemd resolvectl drop in files for dns

Tags: dns, systemd, systemd-resolved

My Setup

- Ubuntu 20.04
- dumb proprietary vpn client which changes /etc/resolv.conf

problem

- each time any interface re-connect, NetworkManager come into play, redo resolv.conf

So far so good.

With resolvectl, I redo DNS settings for the vpn interface and it works fine until next interface re-connect.

```
# resolvectl dns tun0 10.10.10.10
# resolvectl domain tun0 "~example.com ~example.org"
```

How do I make it permanent?

I've try to created the file (and some other variations) without luck.

```
/etc/systemd/network# cat tun0.network 
[Match]
Name=tun0

[Network]
LLMNR=yes
MDNS=no
DNSSEC=no
SERVERS=10.10.10.10
DOMAINS=~example.com ~example.org
```

I would like to know where to drop in files with specific configuration for each interface (vpn or not) for DNS settings.

**More Context**

My objective is to have a file where I can put VPN DNS configuration, for each time NetworkManager redo network configuration take into consideration the proprietary VPN DNS settings, in particularity, the split of resolving certain domains to certain DNS Servers.

Configuring it via resolvectl works as I expected, but it is "forgeted" each time NetworkManager redo network configuration.

I've other vpn connection managed via NetworkManager and it works fine. This vpn connection managed by a proprietary solution doesn't.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you manually editing /etc/resolv.conf? Why are you using 10.10.10.10 with the VPN, and why aren't you using the DNS provided by the VPN? Are you using NetworkManager or netplan? If NM, can't you use the individual connection profiles to set DNS addresses?

Comment: The proprietary VPN client change manually /etc/resolv.conf, which are overwritten each time some interface change is state (NetworkManager doing is job). My goal is to add somewhere the VPN settings (DNS related) for when NetworkManager redo the DNS configuration, also read that configuration. I would like to take advantage of systemd and resolvctl.

Answer (score 1):

In the `terminal`, use `nm-connection-editor`, and create various VPN/regular connection profiles, with these settings...

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you @heynnema, but this is a proprietary VPN client not managable by NM. I've one other VPN (using openconnect) which work as expected in NM, not this proprietary VPN.

Comment: @Pipe Look at `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and see if that helps.

Comment: I've done some attempts with ```nm-connection-editor```, but even with the same device name, Network Manager complains it is an external device and did do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I still did not found the answer, but I've found a workaround.

I've placed a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` which is executed each time a network related events occurs:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "Receive event from ${DEVICE_IFACE:-dummy} ${NM_DISPATCHER_ACTION:-dummy} " >> /tmp/dispatch.log
[[ "${DEVICE_IFACE:-dummy}" = "tun0" ]] && [[ "${NM_DISPATCHER_ACTION:-dummy}" = "up" ]] && {
    resolvectl dns tun0 10.10.10.10
    resolvectl domain tun0 ~example.com ~example.org
    resolvectl dnssec tun0 off 
} >> /tmp/dispatch.log
```

*note* check the permissions, execution bit and must be owned by root